# About ideals in quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am kind of lost in determining if this is true, or how to prove or what are the properties the ring has to have for this to be true:
"Let $R$ be a ring, $I, J$ ideals of $R$ and $\pi: R \to R/I$ the projection map. Then $\pi(J)$ is an ideal of $R/I$ iff $I \subseteq J$".
Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: This is not true, since the projection map is surjective, the image of every ideal is an ideal, see i.e. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200335/is-the-homomorphic-image-of-an-ideal-an-ideal

However, there is a 1-1-correspondence between ideals $J \supseteq I$ and ideals in $R / I$.

Comment: First isomorphism theorem.